# Group departures in Process Modelling Library using AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have setup multiple agents to arrive together at the source but don't know how to force the agents to leave via the sink together. I can use Process Modelling Library only (not Pedestrian or Material Handling ones) and during the process they function independently, therefore, they may have different times in the system and thus different departures into the sink. Is there a way to make the agents that arrived at 1 time to leave together?
Thank you

I honestly don't know how to code it into AnyLogic, haven't used the software much.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Comment: before the sink place a wait block and you will wait until all the agents that need to leave together arrive to that wait block before making them leave... would that work?

Comment: but how would the system know which agents are supposed to leave together?